# How can I beat Andy Kaufman?

Tags: legends-of-wrestling-2

In Legends of Wrestling 2, if you pick Jerry Lawler, you can face off against Andy Kaufman, in homage to their classic match.

It seems that when I wrestle him, no matter how much I pound on him he always gets a big comeback and boost to his health.

Is there a trick to beating Andy Kaufmann?

I rewatched the whole feud from the 70's and saw a faq that states I only have to fight him with Jerry Lawler to unlock him, so I'm going to try again

- first I'm going to try to land a pile driver on him
- then I'm gonna let him beat me

I'll update this question when I figure it out.

Comment: WOW! - that this was put into video game form. Hilarious. Good luck taking down Kaufmann.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft ~@CoryJ Yeah, I'm not making it up ... it's one of the reasons I'm glad GC games work on my Wii :)